# Recovery mode grub partition

Tags: boot, grubrescue

I Deleted a **disk partition** using g-parted and I rebooted the system and it went into grub recovery. It showed a message that no partition found. I am pretty sure it was **not** grub partition. I also do not know grub commands . please help. I somehow reinstalled Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted the partition that the only OS was on, then it would give you that error, or if you deleted the "boot" partition and did not run update-grub on the main disk. You need to reinstall ubuntu at this point and set the main disk itself as the device for bootloader installation, keeping the /boot partition on the same disk as the system, or create boot on a separate partition and don't touch it unless you are specifically adding files, or are wiping the OS off. It seems, from your post, that you have deleted the main partition the OS was on. If you can get a grub-rescue disk burned and are able to locate and boot into your Ubuntu installation, then simply run "sudo update-grub /dev/sda" and reboot, that is if it was simply an old installation that you deleted, causing grub on the mbr to throw that error. SOrry if I can't offer a particularly useful or specific answer, but you were very vague in describing what partition you deleted